# How to update a values of specific fields on csv using nifi?

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have a CSV file where it contains id, name, and salary as fields. The data in my CSV file is like below.

```
id,name,salary
1,Jhon,2345
2,Alex,3456
```

I want to update the current CSV with new id (id*4)

```
id,name,salary
4,Jhon,2345
8,Alex,3456
```

The format of the file in the destination should aslo be CSV. Can anyone tell me the flow? (What processors do I need). I'm very new to nifi. A big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UpdateRecord` processor with the below settings,

```
Record Reader               CSVReader
Record Writer               CSVRecordSetWriter
Replacement Value Strategy  Literal Value
/id                         ${field.value:multiply(4)}
```

then it gives the desired result. Just csv in and csv out.